# how to cancel a domain name registration on aws route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I accidently created domain in route 53 and now its in payment verification stage, I need to cancel it as I was learning and don't require it. can anyone please help how to cancel this process.
[image]

Comment: What is the full **Status** message? If it is requesting you to do something, then you could possibly just _not_ do it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ye it's asking to verify payment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this from AWS support.

"The domain registration invoice was not paid, the domain will not activate until the registration is paid. The invoice will be canceled after 5 days, provided that you do not try and pay it or resubmit the domain registration."

Also, you can read the note mentioned in point 11 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html)

Comment: so, does one just ignore and not pay in order to cancel the request?

Comment: Yes, just ignore it if not paid.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will ignore and not pay. And I see the bills under "Billing" section in my account? will that bill also disappear after 5 days?

Comment: Yes it will disappear

Comment: Bill gets waived in the next billing cycle, that is the following month only after the account holder fails to make payment.